# Import game files into a dictionary

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to create a game and I am trying to organize my pictures and sounds into a dictionary.
The expected format is as follows:
`Media = {"Images": {"Backgrounds": ['EarthGround.png', 'MarsGround.png', ...], "Sprites": [...]}, "Sounds": ["click.wav", ...]}`

[image: Here] is an image of the folder format.

I have written the following code:
`

```
Media = {}

def sortFiles(directory):
    for x in os.listdir(directory):
        if os.path.isdir(f'{directory}/{x}'):
            Media[x] = sortFiles(f'{directory}/{x}')

        elif os.path.isfile(f'{directory}/{x}'):
            return [file for file in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(f'{directory}/{file}')]


sortFiles("Media")

print(Media)
```

`

And the following is the output:
`{'Backgrounds': ['EarthGround.png', 'MarsGround.png'], 'Buttons': None, 'Icons': ['selectionBar.png'], 'Main': ['base.png'], 'Planets': None, 'Sprites': None}`

As shown, the keys "Backgrounds" and "Sprites" aren't in "Images" as expected ("Images": {"Backgrounds": ..., "Sprites": ...}).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Consider abandoning your current buggy recursive approach, and let [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) handle the recursive details for you.

Answer (score 0):

As J_H commented, os.walk() was what I was looking for.
Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).